# Which concept applies here?

Tags: experiment-design, decision-theory

Suppose I want to learn about a random variable $X$ (e.g., whether the subject is infected with Covid). I have already accessed a random variable $Y$ (e.g., an antigen test), which can help me partially learn about $X$. Now I would like to know given $Y$, how much another random variable $Z$ (e.g., nucleic acid test) can help me additionally learn about $X$.
What is the corresponding concept in information theory? Is it conditional mutual information $I(X; Z \vert Y)$ or total correlation?

Edit: I proposed a question, and asked which concept in information theory is a measure of the additional information about $X$ provided by $Z$ given $Y$. I don't quite know what additional details are required.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52754/5038, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/613426/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).